# Rotate an image horizontally?

Tags: java, rotation

Does anyone know of a way to rotate an image horizontally in Java sort of like this?

http://puu.sh/48iLc.png Original

http://puu.sh/48iHN.jpg Rotated

I just got the rotated one from MS Word because I knew they have those type of rotations.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think MS Paint will do it.

Comment: He asked how to do it in Java...

Comment: That's not rotation, that's skew. See here for something that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446494/skewing-an-image-using-perspective-transforms

Comment: @Kon that can be a rotation in 3D around `y` axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referred to as shear in Java (though I call it skew.)

Use the [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) class to "shear" your image. That will produce the effect you want.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html#Java2D-Tutorial-Transforms-Shear) on shearing.