# How to deskew cropped images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have cropped an image using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213413/canvas-cropping-images-in-different-shapes) solution. Is there a way I can deskew the image using source and destination co-ordinates of the corners or another way?

Ideally I want to be able to do this manually without using preset co-ordinates in the script.

For example, a tilted piece of paper in an image [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWKsX.jpg). I crop the image so just the paper is left but then it is still tilted. So i want to make it as if I am looking directly at it.

Comment: For future posts, it would be good to post example javascript or jQuery code so that it could be corrected.  Also, there are various sub-sites of stack overflow that would possibly be a better forum for this, if specific code is not involved.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "use a transformation matrix". [Skewing an image using Perspective Transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446494/skewing-an-image-using-perspective-transforms)'s top answer covers the usage of those in pretty significant detail.

A shear + scale is the easiest, but would warp the image. So you'll need to mix in a perspective map if you want to deal with the warping of the image as objects move "in" or "out" (along the z-plane) of perspective.